# VB connection to 1and1 mysql database not working

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, connection

Right, I know this is a heavily documented issue. I also know that there are many 'answers' out there. However, not one of these answers fixes the issue I have. I have tried many different websites and many different threads so you can trust me when I say I have tried everything. Here is my code for a new account form which is part of my program. My main issue is that when i try to connect, the program cannot reach the database. It states that "it is unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts". This is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class NewAccount
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
Public Sub connect()
    Dim DatabaseName As String = "db709866308"
    Dim server As String = "db709866308.db.1and1.com"
    Dim userName As String = "db709866308"
    Dim password As String = "*******"
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)
    Try
        conn.Open()

        MsgBox("Connected")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim Password As String
    Dim Password2 As String
    Dim userName As String
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Encryption goes under this line''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''





    Dim plainText As String
    Dim cipherText As String

    Dim passPhrase As String
    Dim saltValue As String
    Dim hashAlgorithm As String
    Dim passwordIterations As Integer
    Dim initVector As String
    Dim keySize As Integer

    plainText = Pword.Text     ' original plaintext

    passPhrase = "Pas5pr@se"        ' can be any string
    saltValue = "s@1tValue"         ' can be any string
    hashAlgorithm = "SHA1"          ' can be "MD5"
    passwordIterations = 2          ' can be any number
    initVector = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8" ' must be 16 bytes
    keySize = 256                   ' can be 192 or 128

    cipherText = RijndaelSimple.Encrypt _
    (
        plainText,
        passPhrase,
        saltValue,
        hashAlgorithm,
        passwordIterations,
        initVector,
        keySize
    )

    plainText = RijndaelSimple.Decrypt _
    (
        cipherText,
        passPhrase,
        saltValue,
        hashAlgorithm,
        passwordIterations,
        initVector,
        keySize
    )





    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Encryption goes above this line''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Try

        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to Server. " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO `auth` VALUES User.text, ciphertext"))
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Couldn't Access Database")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I would also like to emphasise that this is not the full code, only the parts that include some form of connection.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not at all clear what the problem is, what you are (not) asking or what that title means

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix, made it more obvious

Comment: You need to consult the documentation for that host.  In most cases with those hosted sites/services you do not connect directly.